# Hreflang (Search Console) & arabic words in url

Tags: urlencode, arabic, hreflang

I have a website with urls like this

htxp://ar.dzmeteo.com/أحوال-الطقس-في-أدرار

```
<link rel="alternate" href="htxp://ar.dzmeteo.com/أحوال-الطقس-في-أدرار" hreflang="ar" />
```

the problem is that in search console arabic urls are decoded, like this:

htxp://ar.dzmeteo.com/%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%82%D8%B3-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A3%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1

and i get a lot of errors

[errors in search console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xmQZ.png)